# MappingException with root cause NullpointerException

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

### Context

I have a neo4j 2.3.X running on localhost, connected to an API using:

- Neo4j-OGM
- Spring boot
- Spring security
- Spring hateoas
- Spring logging

All of this running on a java-8-oracle JVM

I tested this on windows and linux, same issue.

### Problem summary

When I do a GET request on my api, with every endpoint (I tested them all), neo4j-ogm is raising a MappingException:

```
2016-02-24 09:52:59.821 ERROR 7496 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of com.bnstips.api.database.model.BnSClass] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Utils.coerceTypes(Utils.java:80) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.annotations.FieldWriter.write(FieldWriter.java:69) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.tryMappingAsSingleton(GraphEntityMapper.java:221) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationship(GraphEntityMapper.java:258) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapRelationships(GraphEntityMapper.java:245) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:143) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:117) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:81) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:73) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:110) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:97) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.0-M02.jar:na]
    at com.bnstips.api.database.GenericService.findAll(GenericService.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.bnstips.api.endpoint.ClassEndpoint.getClasses(ClassEndpoint.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

I stopped the stack trace copy at the first line where my own code is, but if needed, I can copy the whole trace.

My project is done like the first example here: http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/

So I have a `GenericService<T>` extended by all my Services with CRUD operations.

Here is `ClassEndpoint.getClasses(long id)` implementation:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<BnSClass> getClasses(){

    Iterable<BnSClass> classes = this.service.findAll();
    classes.forEach((c) -> {
        c.createLinks();
    });
    return classes;
}
```

and findAll method:

```
 @Override
 public Iterable<T> findAll() {
     return session.loadAll(getEntityType(), DEPTH_LIST);//DEPTH_LIST is -1
 }
```

and finally, `Class` model:

```
@NodeEntity(label="Class")
public class BnSClass extends Entity<BnSClass>{

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="TIP_FOR", direction="INCOMING")
    @JsonIgnore private Set<Tip> tips = new HashSet<Tip>(); 

    @Relationship(type="USED_BY", direction="INCOMING")
    @JsonIgnore private Set<Build> builds = new HashSet<Build>();

    ...Getters and Setters ommited
}
```

### Database

My database is so simple that I can show it to you by a simple screenshot:

[image: Database structure]

`:Class` nodes are using only one property: `name`.

EDIT:

### pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M02</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

EDIT 2:
After some tries I managed to get rid of the bug, but for that I have to set  DEPTH_ENTITY to 1 but it only fixes `findAll()` queries, so this is not a solution, but it might give a way to find a solution.

Comment: You're right, changing the depth is not a solution. Without the classes for Tip and Build, I'm unable to reproduce this. Possible to share a complete failing test?

Comment: @Luanne I found the problem, but I'm not sure this is an issue. Will post an answer to describe it, and if it's an issue, I'll report it on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found where it was from, let me explain:

`BnSClass` extends `Commentable<T>`, Here is `Commentable<T>`:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class Commentable<T> extends Rateable<T>{

    @Relationship(type="COMMENTED", direction="INCOMING")
    @JsonIgnore private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>(); 

    public Set<Comment> getComments(){
        return this.comments;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Commentable<T>` adds a set of `Comment` to my object, and the problem was coming from `Comment`:

```
@NodeEntity
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "content", "score"})
public class Comment extends Commentable<Comment> implements CreationDate{

    @Relationship(type="COMMENTED", direction="OUTGOING")
    @JsonIgnore private Entity<?> subject;

    private String content;

    private long edited;

    private boolean deleted = false;

    @JsonIgnore private Authored authored;
}
```

If I set `subject` type to `Entity` rawtype, it works like a charm, but if I let `Entity<?>` as type, it produces this error. Since almost every resources in my api are commentable or have a Set, this error occured everytime I was fetching from the database.

N.B: Every node entity inherits from `Entity<T>`, which is the `Entity<T>` class provided in neo4j-ogm guide.